# Asp.Net Core authorization with a webconfig

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, authorization

We are migrating our ASP.NET backoffice to a ASP.NET core and I have stuck with an old authorization approach.

There is a website and backoffice. 
Those two share login cookies (SSO, single sign on).

Website has 200 user and only 3 are administrators.
Administrators are configured via webconfig while we have only few that are never changed.

Actually all users **have login credentials to a backoffice** because of SSO (login with a shared cookies thru the public website).

Today all people that are not authorized are filtered with a backoffice web.config:

```
 <location path="Default.aspx">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
    <allow users="superadmin@backoffice.com" />
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

So IIS will do the job and authorization cookies are ignored for other people.

Any clues how to sign out the users that are not in the list and has login cookies that granted on our website for a new ASP.NET core solution? As I understand this webconfig configuration is not a case anymore...

Comment: Too many options, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/?view=aspnetcore-2.1 so dig further.

Comment: @LexLi The question is not about the authorization by itself, It's implemented already. But the thing is that  users already authenticated via SSO and they have same roles, claims and etc. But anyway I should restrict some of those based on the list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct, web.configs are not used for that anymore.

What you need to do:

1. Register [cookie-authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) using middleware and extension method for `IApplicationBuilder` and `IServiceCollection` and configure the cookies name
2. Use the [configuration-builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration) to build your configuration using
   `appsettings.json` files and/or environment variables. There is a
   default configuration that is being build by the webhost, which adds
   `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.{Environment}.json` and
   `environment-variables` to a configuration that you can inject into
   your startup class (the vs template has that included). Here you will store that information about which users are allowed, all others won't be
3. Write a custom policy to deny all other users like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.1).